# Python subprocess module and PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have following code to check CNAME for list of URLs. The equivalent bash command is "dig mail.yahoo.com |grep CNAME"

The 'hostname.txt' file has list of URLs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
with open('hostname.txt') as hl:
    for host in hl:
            print host
            p1 = Popen(["dig", host], stdout=PIPE)
            p2 = Popen (["grep", "CNAME"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
            p1.stdout.close()
            output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

I don't get desired output from above python code. I get below output.

`$` python dev/cname_check.py

mail.yahoo.com

gmail.com

google.com

`$`

Please let me know what am I missing. I followed example from here, http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print `host` but not `output`, so that's why you only see the hosts listed. Just add a `print output` at the end...

Comment: Thanks that worked! I also had to add 'string.strip(host)' to strip the output from file.